# Cant lock only the column letter by dollar sign ($)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I can't lock the columns when I extending the variables at the horizontal axis, but vertically it's working great (just like if I don't use anything...):

```
=$A2
```

Instead, it's locking everything just like when I using this:

```
=$A$2
```

Is there any workaround for this? I need to extend the columns on the horizontal axis, because I creating a printing template table for QR Codes.

UPDATE:

I want to achive this, when I duplicating the cell with the bottom right corner:

```
=A1 | =A2 | =A3 | =A4 | ...
→
```

Answer (score 2):

Copying the expression =$A2 horizontally will always result in =$A2. This is intentional, since '$' is the 'locker' symbol. If you need specific part of the reference to change you shouldn't use a '$' before it.

`=$A2 →  =$A2
   ↓
=$A3`

although...

`=A$2 →  =B$2
   ↓
=A$2`

---

Your specific problem cannot be achieved via referencing. However there are many functions that can handle the situation. For example you can use transpose(*your_range_definition*).

Please notice that in some spreadsheets you must use ctrl+shift+enter to apply definitions to a range. So to 'mirror' the range A2:A4 you should select B1:D1, type =transpose(A2:A4) and press ctrl+shift+enter.

Another approach can be to use the index() and column() functions. You may enter to B1 the expression =index($A$1:$A$5, column(B1))  and drag or copy it to the right. No ctrl+shift+enter is needed this way. Here, you query the column number of the current cell and using this number you get the required row from the first (static) column.

Comment: What?  This answer is a little confusing to understand.

Comment: Arrows are intended to show the direction of copy. This is how references in spreadsheets work.

Comment: Thank You! The arrow examples are great, easy to understand. Is there any way to achieve what I want? A guy solved me a way that the spreadsheet warming up all of my 4+4 cpu cores and its need 10-20sec to generate 15 piece of qr code...

Comment: Possibly yes. Could you augment your question with some pointers? I was unable to understand exactly what you would like to achieve.

Comment: I updated my question.